# MSAL get_accounts() method correctly returns the account id, but only 'username' has an empty value

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using the default user flow in AADB2C and adding taro as user.
When I use the get_accounts() method in MSAL for python, only username is empty as shown below.

- home_account_id: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx（The value registered as taro）
- environment: xxxxxx.b2clogin.com
- username: ""
- authority_type: MSSTS
- local_account_id: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx（The value registered as taro）
- realm: xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com

What part of the username in each value returned by get_accounts() is referring to that I have set up in AADB2C?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to make the question concise in my own way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a page that explains.

"MSAL Python token cache usage pattern starts with querying all existing accounts by get_accounts(...), which supports a username parameter as filter. That username data is populated by a preferred_username claim inside the ID Token.

By default, that claim is missing in many of the Azure AD B2C scenarios."

As far as using AADB2C, I have found that we should consider a method other than referencing username.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Developing-an-AAD-B2C-app-with-MSAL-Python#caching-with-b2c-in-msal-python